# what is the difference between the capacitance values 225j and 225k x rated

Tags: capacitor

PLEASE what is the difference between the capacitance values 225j and 225k x rated capacitors?

Comment: Depending on manufacturer, it is usually either capacitive tolerance or voltage rating. The manufacturer information would be useful or a full part number even if it is just the code on the part.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in their nominal capacitance value. However, the 225J capacitor will have a 5% tolerance, and the 225K capacitor will have a 10% tolerance.

There is a brief explanation of the tolerance codes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#Capacitor_markings) but you can find more detail on this by Googling "capacitor codes".